# Change UIAlertView message

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a problem with UIAlertView message, I need to change alert message with loop

First,

I declare this in implementation

```
NSString *alertMessage;
UIAlertView *theAlert;
```

and

```
- (IBAction)doSearching:(id)sender
{
    theAlart = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Searching..." 
               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [theAlart show];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self 
             selector:@selector(searchAfterAlertShow) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


- (void)searchAfterAlertShow
{
   for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++) {
       alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Searching... (%d/%d)"
                                                         , i, [dataArray count]];
       NSLog(@"%@", alertMessage);


 // do something here


       if (i == [dataArray count]) {
           [theAlart dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
       }

   }

}
```

and in Alert delegate

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [theAlart setMessage: alertMessage];
}
```

The Log is writing:

Searching... (1/8)

Searching... (2/8)

...

Searching... (8/8)

but the alert message changed at the end of loop

Comment: What do you mean that the message change? What should be the expected message?

Comment: I need to change message with another string

Answer (score 0):

If the operations are too fast, the dismiss animation will take longer than the loop itself.

Most UI animations are async, therefore they happen in the background and they don't wait. you can either delay the operation to compensate for the animation duration, or pass `NO` for animated parameter in `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated`